# ajax returns the html code of current page instead of json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm using the `$.ajax` function in JQuery to get JSON from a file. HTML, JavaScript and json files are in the same directory. The problem is that when i print the data returned from the success callback function it prints the HTML markup of the HTML page instead of the JSON.

Here is my `data.json` file content:

```
{
  "products":[
    {
      "skuNum":"SKU# 105423-2",
      "brand":"nike running shoes",
      "section":"men > shoe > Running shoes",
      "img":"392232_004_ss_01.jpg",
      "price":500
    },
    {
      "skuNum":"SKU# 105423-2",
      "brand":"south face jacket",
      "section":"women > Apparel > jackets",
      "img":"jacket.jpeg",
      "price":800
    }
  ]
}
```

my JQuery:

```
$(function () {
      $.ajax({
          type: 'GET',
          URL:'data.json',
          success:function (data) {
              console.log(data);
          },
          error:function (error) {
              console.log('error')
          }
      });
});
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="ajax.css">
    <script src="jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<nav>
    <a href="#">Home</a>
    <a href="#" id="products">Products</a>
    <a href="#">Help</a>
</nav>
<div class="container">

</div>
<script src="ajax.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is a snippet of the output:

> [image: output snippet]

Comment: See below answer, and I'd like to add that the error function has 3 parameters: `function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)` - see http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javascript is case sensitive. The correct property for `URL` is `url` in `$.ajax` options object

When you provide an incorrectly spelled property it will get ignored and the proper property will return undefined.

In this case since it is `URL` the request would get made to current page since no `url` is available in the options

Change:

```
URL:'data.json',
```

To

```
url:'data.json',
```

Comment: Thank you , i appreciate it.