# Javascript XMLHttpRequest and Jquery $.ajax both are returning the current page HTML code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

## The problem

Hello i want to start off hoping all of y'all are having a fantastic day! I'm having a really weird problem that i have never came across before. I have a bootstrap navigation form with two fields, an input for a email and a field for the password.

[image: Picture of Bootstrap navigation bar with forms]

When the user submits the form it calls to an AddEventListener which is waiting for a click of the login button. and after that is called it validates(Server Side Validation) the form of the entered data. After both the email_validated and password_validated is both equal to true it calls to a function called checkLogin(email, password){email = entered email in field, password = entered password in field}. In the checkLogin function it called to a JQuery $.ajax({}) call which sends the email and password field to a php document located in /scripts/checkLogin.php. However instead of it returning "Hello"(For testing purposes) is returns the entire HTML code for the current page(As shown above)

[image: Ajax request response]

### JQuery $.ajax({}) code

Here i have the code for the $.ajax({}) call.

[image: The entire $.ajax({}) call]

### Console

I'm not getting any errors in the console except for the XHR finished loading: POST

[image: Console]

#### Other Pictures

Here are some other pictures that i am including to hopefully give yall a better idea of the structure.

[image: file structure]

[image: checkLogin.php code]

#### Note

I just want to add that i have checked Stackoverflow for similar problems and other people have had this problem but they solutions did not work on my code. I have also tried just using a regular XMLHttpRequest and the same problem occurred, i'm honestly not sure what is wrong with the code for i have never had this problem before. Thank you for taking the time to read this i appreciate any help that i can get with solving this. I'm not the best with $.ajax({}) or XMLHttpRequest and im willing to make any changed to the code to try to get this to work. Below is my code for the entire javascript validation(server side).

### Code

```
      <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" method="POST">

        <input class="form-control mr-sm-2 nav-login" type="text" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Email" name="email" value="trest@gmail.com" id="email">

        <input type="password" name="password" autocomplete="off" class="form-control nav-login mr-sm-2" placeholder="Password" value="password" name="password" id="password">

        <button class="btn btn-success my-2 my-sm-0 nr" type="button" name="login_button" id="login_button">Login &nbsp;<i class="fas fa-sign-in-alt"></i></button>

      </form>


      <script>
      document.getElementById('login_button').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();

      // const email_regex = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;

      let email_validated = true;
      let password_validated = true;



      let email = document.getElementById('email');
      let password = document.getElementById('password');

      // let email_length = email.value.length;
      // let password_length = password.value.length;




      //
      //
      // if(!email_length){
      //   email.classList.add('is-invalid');
      // }else{
      //   if(!email_regex.test(email.value)){
      //     email.classList.add('is-invalid');
      //   }else{
      //     email.classList.remove('is-invalid');
      //     email.classList.add('is-valid');
      //     email_validated = true;
      //
      //   }
      // }
      // if(!password_length){
      //   password.classList.add('is-invalid');
      // }else{
      //   password.classList.remove('is-invalid');
      //   password.classList.add('is-valid');
      //   password_validated = true;
      // }


      if(email_validated === true && password_validated === true){
        checkLogin(email.value, password.value);
      }
    });
    function checkLogin(email, password){
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/scripts/checkLogin.php',
        data: {
          'email': email,
          'password': password
        },
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: (result) => {
          alert(result);
        }
      });
    }
</script>
```

#### Links to the other StackOverFlow question

[ajax returns the html code of current page instead of json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52189180/ajax-returns-the-html-code-of-current-page-instead-of-json)

Comment: You didn't post enough to know what's wrong, but a guess is that your login button is not marked with `type=button`, so it's submitting the form and reloading the original page.

Comment: My bad about that let me edit it and add the code to it. My apologies

Comment: Also, generally *images* of code etc are not nearly as useful as the actual code.

Comment: I have all of my javascript(even commented out) code added, i just got done adding the form code too.

Comment: If the `alert(result)` shows the content the `index.php` generates, then you probably configured your webserver in a way that `index.php` responds to all requests.

Comment: You know that is an exellent point! i forgot that i had configured it, give me a second and i will turn it off and test it.

Comment: @t.niese that was the problem i can't believe i didnt even think about that causing the problem. I thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I was the way my server was configured with xammp as t.niese said.